# Program logs in to same file

Tags: python-3.x, class, logging

I created class that takes a url as parameter, also I have a list of urls and i am invoking class for every url. I have enabled logging to see why it fails for certiain url. However i got logs into one file.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('bot')
        self.logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
        self.handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        self.handler_format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(lineno)d:%(filename)s(%(process)d) - %(message)s")

        logging.basicConfig(filename=self.data['path']['logs']+'/{}/{}'.format(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), url.replace('/','-')),
                filemode='w',
                format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                level=logging.INFO)
```

file where class is being invoked:

```
from file.py import MyClass

for i in urls:
    obj = MyClass(i)
```

I also tried **del obj** after iteration but it doesn't help. I will hugely appreciate and hint.

Comment: You want every class variable to be logged into a separate file?

Comment: yes, into file named after url